# xforms-inspector conflicts with <script></script> in *.xsl

Tags: orbeon, xforms

After moving from 14.04 to 16.04 a project is no longer working.  `<fr:xforms-inspector />` conflicts with the `<script></script>`  in the *.xsl-file. See code below.

( Ubuntu 16.04 / tomcat8 / Orbeon Forms 2016.3.201612302139 / firefox )

**Questions**

- Why is the `<fr:xforms-inspector />` suddenly conflicting with this tag?
- Why not in 14.04. Is this a bug, which needed to be reported, or is this my error, that this is no longer working?
- Is there a way to solve it?
- Has it something to do with: https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/actions/scripting.html that this way is a deprecated?

**blubb.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
>
<head>
    <title>Blubb</title>
    <xf:model>
        <xf:instance id="instance_stylesheet" src="blubb.xsl" />
    </xf:model>
</head>

<body>
    <fr:xforms-inspector />
</body></html>
```

**blubb.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template>
    <html>
        <!-- inserting the script tag, results in the error.
             It does not matter, whats in it. -->       
        <script>

        </script>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Below the webpage created by orbeon from the files. The inspector has no code view and those `\n` belong to it too. Every other behavior is also effected randomly.*

[image: Resulting error. the \n ... belonging to the error too.]

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was do to Ubuntu. But how can we reproduce the Would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here?

Comment: As fare, as I know, those two code snippets are enough when thy put in the files and run in an orbeon enviroment to reproduce the error. There is no need to add more code. If I've forgot something, please tell and you will recieve the missing files asap.

Comment: @avernet Was it possible to reproduce the behavior? Do you need some more informations? Please let me know.

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce [the issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3271), and fixed it. We're planning to have the fix in Orbeon Forms 2017.1. Here is a [test build](https://s3.amazonaws.com/orbeon-builds/orbeon/orbeon-forms-pe/1303/1303.2/build/distrib/orbeon-2017.1.201706192334-PE.war) for you to verify that everything works properly. You'll let me know if it works for you with this build.

Comment: Just curious: did you get a chance to test the build linked in my previous comment?

Comment: Thx for all your help, work and direct contact to the developer! I tried to test it, but because of a missing licence I had noch chance to do so. I did a workarround and ecxluded the <script> - tag into the head of the mainfile.

Comment: Sorry, I should have linked to a CE test build. But now 2017.1 is released, so you can [grab a final copy](http://www.orbeon.com/download), in case you want to keep the `<script>`, or maybe more importantly, want to benefit from some of the enhancements in this new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3271) is fixed since [Orbeon Forms 2017.1](http://blog.orbeon.com/2017/06/orbeon-forms-20171.html), so if you're hitting this problem and using an earlier version, I'd recommend you [upgrade to 2017.1](http://www.orbeon.com/download).